# Regular Expression representing the following language

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am having trouble understanding how to write a regular expression for the set of words that contain at least two *b*'s and at least two *a*'s, where the alphabet is {a,b}.

I understand that set of words that contain at least two *b*'s is: **[1]** `(a+b)*b(a+b)*b(a+b)*` and the set of words that contain at least two *a*'s is: **[2]** `(a+b)*a(a+b)*a(a+b)*`.  In addition, I understand that the set of words that contain at least one *a* and at least one *b* is: **[3]** `(a+b)*(ab+ba)(a+b)*` (or at least *I think* that is correct).

I know the easy solution would be to use an intersection between **[1]** and **[2]**; however, I would like to understand how to accomplish this without using an intersection.

I know I would need to have `(a+b)*` at the beginning and at the end to say that any string made up of *a*'s and *b*'s can be at the beginning and at the end.  But I am having trouble understanding the logic between those two points.

Just looking for some direction as I do not know where to go from there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have written (a+b)*(ab+ba)(a+b)*

This contains atleast 1 a & at least 1 b.
So what are ab & ba ? ab & ba are permutations of string you can form with at least one a & at least one b !
As you are asking for hint,
You can write something like 
(a+b)* (All Permutations of aabb ) (a+b)*

Hope this helps.

There are just 6 permutations (4!/2!2!)  of aabb here, so it wont be hard to calcualate them ! .

Comment: Figured it might be just writing all possible permutations but wasn't sure if there was another approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Random junk is $(a \mid b)^*$, then (at least) two $b$ is $(a \mid b)^* b (a \mid b)^* b (a \mid b)^*$. ($b$s separated by junk). Two $a$, two $b$ is one of $aabb$, $abab$, $abba$, $baba$, $bbaa$, $baab$ (this checks, there must be $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ of them). Fill out with junk:

$$(a \mid b)^* a (a \mid b)^* a (a \mid b)^* b (a \mid b)^* b (a \mid b)^* \mid \dotsb$$

(fill out all the 6 alternatives above with $(a \mid b)^*$ between fixed symbols, alternate between them).

Yes, very ugly, but easy to see it does the job.